# Подскажите как сбросить и остановить таймер

Tags: javascript

Есть код таймера, но не понятно как его остановить и сбросить.

```
function times(numb, int_id) {
    var _ = numb;
    if (_ <= 0) {
        clearInterval(int_id);
        alert('Время истекло!');
    }
    return (_ < 10) ? '0' + _ : _;
}

function interval(int_id, numb) {
    var span = document.getElementById(int_id);
    int_id = setInterval(function() {
        span.innerHTML = times(numb--, int_id);
    }, 1000);
}

interval('codeCountDown', 120);//запускаем
```

Как при нажатии на кнопку сбросить и остановить его, не могу разобраться?

Comment: Запустил у себя ваш скрипт... работает

Comment: Да, он работает. Мне нужно его остановить по событию, например при нажатии на кнопку. Я думаю какая-то доп. функция, наверное, нужна?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем кнопку для сброса интервала
Объявляем глобальную переменную для хранения ID интервала **timerID**

```
let timerID;

function times(numb, int_id) {
  var _ = numb;
  if (_ <= 0) {
    clearInterval(int_id);
    alert('Время истекло!');
  }
  return (_ < 10) ? '0' + _ : _;
}

function interval(int_id, numb) {
  var span = document.getElementById(int_id);
  timerID = setInterval(function() { // Записываем ID
    span.innerHTML = times(numb--, timerID); // Передаем в функцию
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timerID);
}
// Вешаем событие нажатия кнопки
document.getElementById('stopInterval').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(timerID) // Останавливаем интервал
})

interval('codeCountDown', 3);//запускаем
```

Код кнопки

```
<button id='stopInterval'>Стоп</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! То, что нужно!