# Как задать время отсчета таймера на javascript?

Tags: javascript, время, таймер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать время таймера с помощью кнопки?
Таймер написан, время задаю в коде. Есть также три картинки. Необходимо изменять (задавать) время таймера в зависимости от выбора картинки. То есть, если пользователь выбирает первую картинку, то таймер одна минута, вторую - две минуты и т.д.
Сам таймер запускается через отдельную кноку старт.

Код таймера:

```js
let timer = 0.1;
let amountTime = timer * 60;

function calculateTime (){
  const countdown = document.querySelector("#countdown");

  let minutes = Math.floor(amountTime/60);
  let seconds = amountTime%60;

  if (seconds < 10){
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  countdown.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  amountTime--;

  if (amountTime < 0) {
    stopTimer();
    amountTime = 0;
  }

  function stopTimer(){
    clearInterval();
  }
}

const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', startTimer);

function startTimer () {
  setInterval(calculateTime,1000);
}
```

Мне нужно переменную timer задавать через выбор картинки (нажатие кнопки) пользователем.

Код кнопок в HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="button1" value="5">SOFT-BOILED</button>
    <img src="Picture1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="button2" value="6">MEDIUM-BOILED</button>
    <img src="Picture2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="button3" value="7">HARD-BOILED</button>
    <img src="Picture3.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Ставлю addEventListener на все три кнопки - не срабатывает.

Comment: По событию onClick вызывать функцию с таймером. В чем именно возникли сложности? Покажите HTML разметку и код, с которым возникли сложности

Comment: Задаю время через переменную 
let timer = 0.1;
let amountTime = timer * 60;
Надо, чтоб время выбиралось из этих кнопок 
<div id="container">
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="button1" value="5">SOFT-BOILED</button>
            <img src="Picture1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="button2" value="6">MEDIUM-BOILED</button>
            <img src="Picture2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
       
    </div>

Comment: Мне надо привязать событие "клик по кнопке" к переменной timer . причем кнопок три и у  каждой разное время

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос и укажите это все там. Для редактирования, нажмите кнопку "[Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1498795/edit)". Возможно [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460161/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80/1460172#1460172) поможет в вашем вопросе

Comment: Исправил. Надеюсь, стало понятнее.

Comment: document.querySelector("#btn"); и const countdown = document.querySelector("#countdown");   В HTML нет btn и countdown

Comment: Я просто не весь код HTML выложил. Не думал, что надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать таким образом..

```js
let timer = 0.1;
let amountTime = timer * 60;

function calculateTime() {
  const countdown = document.querySelector("#countdown");

  let minutes = Math.floor(amountTime / 60);
  let seconds = amountTime % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  countdown.textContent = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  amountTime--;

  if (amountTime < 0) {
    stopTimer();
    amountTime = 0;
  }

  function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval();
  }
}
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', startTimer));

function startTimer(e) {
let btn = e.target
console.log('countdown!', btn);
amountTime = btn.value * 60;
  setInterval(calculateTime, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="button1" value="5">SOFT-BOILED</button>
    <img src="Picture1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="button2" value="6">MEDIUM-BOILED</button>
    <img src="Picture2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="button3" value="7">HARD-BOILED</button>
    <img src="Picture3.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="countdown">00:00</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Супер! То, что надо. Спасибо огромное.